# Spring Boot connect to Postgres database on Heroku

Tags: spring, postgresql, heroku, spring-boot

I've been playing around with a Spring Boot app deployed on Heroku but I've stumbled upon an error that I can't seem to find a solution.

I'm trying to connect to a Postgres database following the Heroku tutorial ([link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku#connecting-to-a-database)) but I get this error over and over again:

```
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]:
Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No supported DataSource type found
```

Here's the config file I'm using:

```
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.removeAbandoned=true
```

And the DatabaseConfig class:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {
    @Bean @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, have you correctly added the Maven dependency for the PostGreSQL JDBC driver (pom.xml) ? `<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>9.4-1201-jdbc4</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Yes - I also have the Maven dependency added

Comment: Did you create and bind to a PostgreSQL service using the Heroku command-line ? 
$ heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev

Comment: Yeap - I've followed the steps from the tutorial. Thanks @Georgesvanhoutte for taking a look. It's really frustrating that I'm stuck with this error :(

Comment: I struggled with heroku last year. Forget it. Use pivotal cloud foundry with Spring tool suite our Command line. It works perfectly.

Comment: I'll research pivotal cloud also. Thanks for the tip. I'll also try to dig a bit on these error - I would like to understand what's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered this same exact issue and managed to solve it. The issue is not specific to Heroku, because it can be reproduced by running the app locally as well using the same configuration.

According to the stacktrace it is clear that a DataSource has not been found in the class path. According to Spring Boot documentation, found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database), you can either use **spring-boot-starter-jdbc** or **spring-boot-starter-data-jpa** to automatically get **tomcat-jdbc**, which appears to be the preferred one in Spring Boot.

I added the following dependency to pom.xml, which solved the problem:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```